# добавить элемент в список

Tags: javascript

В чем ошибка?пишет, что pushAlphabet не определен в HTMLInputElement.onclic. Не понимаю, что надо исправить.

```js
class FSM {
    constructor(alphabet, state, transition, label){
        this.alphabet = alphabet;
        this.state = state;
        this.transition = transition;
        this.label = label;
    }
    pushAlphabet();
    pushStates();
    pushTransition();
};

function pushAlphabet() {
    var alph = document.getElementById("inputAddAlphabet").value;
    if(alph.length == 1){
        var li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = alph;
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);

        var removeBtn = document.createElement("input");
        removeBtn.type="button";
        removeBtn.value = "Удалить";
        removeBtn.onclick = remove;
        li.appendChild(removeBtn);
        document.getElementById("list").appendChild(li);
    } else { alert('Вы можете добавить только один символ!');}
}


function remove(e) {
    var el = e.target;
    el.parentNode.remove();
}
```

```html
<div class="alphabet">
        <label>Алфавит</label>
        <form>
            <input id="inputAddAlphabet" type="text">
            <input type="button" value="Добавить" onclick="pushAlphabet()">
        </form>
        <ul id="list"></ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript не распарсился из-за синтаксических ошибок.

```
class FSM {
    constructor(alphabet, state, transition, label){
        this.alphabet = alphabet;
        this.state = state;
        this.transition = transition;
        this.label = label;
    }
    //pushAlphabet();
    //pushStates();
    //pushTransition();
};

function pushAlphabet() {
  ...
}
...
```